Centring item difficulties on zero using rasch function in ltm
I'm using ltm package to calculate item difficulties from test responses. This is how I'm doing it:
model.1pl <- rasch(dfTestMatrix)

# proportion correct (PC)
dfPC <- data.frame(colnames(model.1pl$X), summary$perc) %>%
  dplyr::select(uiid = "colnames.model.1pl.X.", PC = "X1")

# item difficulties
dfItemParams <- data.frame(coef(model.1pl, prob = FALSE))
dfItemBank <- data.frame(colnames(model.1pl$X), dfItemParams$Dffclt, dfItemParams$Dscrmn) %>%
  rename(uiid="colnames.model.1pl.X.", b="dfItemParams.Dffclt", a="dfItemParams.Dscrmn")

# compare difficulties and proportions correct
dfItemDetails <- merge(dfItemBank, dfPC, by = "uiid", all = TRUE) 

What I am wanting to do is centring item difficulties instead of person abilities on zero; however I'm not sure how this is done using the ltm package. Has anyone done this before? Is there a way it can be done? I've read through the documentation for ltm, but I don't see a way to do this.
I ran the above code on my data, and noticed that the person abilities are centred rather than the item difficulties.

The ltm package uses Marginal Maximum Likelihood Estimation, which assumes a normal distribution of person parameters centered at 0. This is described by Rizopoulos (2006), and also in contrast to CML by Mair and Hatzinger (2007). So, I don't believe there would be a way to change that.
However, I don't see why one couldn't perform a linear transformation on item difficulties if you were so inclined. Is your goal simply to compare the item difficulties to the proportion correct? If so, you can just mean center them:
dfItemDetails <- dplyr::mutate(dfItemDetails, b_mc = b - mean(b))

It's an interval scale, so it doesn't much matter where 0 ends up. Note that if you plan on doing any comparisons with person ability, you would have to make the same transformation to person scores, or else your wright maps and log-odds and such will be off.
Depending on your goals, you might also consider using conditional maximum likelihood from the eRm package. Instead of assuming a normal distribution of person parameters like MML, with CML we assume that raw scores are a sufficient statistic to determine person parameters. This allows for person-free item assessment, which has some advantages if you're more interested in the items than the people. It produces centered item parameters (in my experience at least), but person parameters that are not centered.
That all being said, having your parameters centered around 0 is just as arbitrary as having them centered at -1.72. I wouldn't worry about it unless you have some good reason to transform them.
